# Can anyone help me draw this icon through css?

Tags: css, icons

[image]

I don't know much about how to create icons through CSS, but I just wanted to know if there is a way I can draw the above icon using it.

Comment: I can only make a circle using border-radius:50%

Comment: CSS is for styling, not drawing icons. Wouldnt photoshop be better?

Comment: And can you draw a line? Can you transform a line?

Comment: I have made this one through Photoshop, but I don't want an image, I want it on a webpage and want to reduce the loading time.

Comment: I have no idea about transformation, could you please help me out?

Answer (score 6):

## Yes!

That said, is there a particular reason not to use and image, icon or [glyph](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/clock-o/)?

## [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5xn8e/2/)

HTML

```
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    border-radius:999px;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background:#59ABD5;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
div:before, div:after {
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    content:'';
    background:white;
    border-radius:5px;
}
div:after {
    left:45px;
    width:8px;
    height:45px;
    top:10px;
}
div:before {
    left:18px;
    width:40px;
    height:8px;
    top:60px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-50deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-50deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-50deg);
    transform: rotate(-50deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Font awesome has a large selection of fonts you can work with.

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/